# Дайте дельный совет, как сделать чтобы программа считывала выборку блюд

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Здравствуйте, я только начинаю программировать на android. И мне нужно написать программу с выбором блюд из меню и общей стоимостью заказа. Программа будет выглядеть так, на экране будет список из блюд со стоимостью и при заказе ставиться галочка на против выбранного блюда, затем формируется заказ из выбранных блюд со стоимостью и в конце общий итог заказа. 
Помогите разобраться или дайте дельный совет, как сделать чтобы программа считывала выборку блюд, выводила её на экран и суммировала общую стоимость.

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень объемный, уточните пожалуйста на конкретных примерах что вам не ясно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Список блюд кастомный `ListView`
2. В строке `ListView` кроме прочего живет `Checkbox`
3. При нажатии на `Checkbox` срабатывает хэндлер, который складывает (или наоборот убирает) в корзину выбранное блюдо
4. Дальше расписывать?

Походу вы взвалили на себя непоъемную задачу. Попроще что-нибудь сделайте - например для начала список стран при выборе страны печатается столица страны